# Full text index search for complex query in Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, full-text-indexing

I am trying to perform full text index search using EF 6.0. I am using IDbCommandInterceptor (http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch) perform Full text search but it is throwing me this exception:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'FirstName'
>   because it is not full-text indexed.

Linq query:

```
ListOfEmployees = _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee) 
.Include(x => x.Tags)
.Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences)
.Where(x => x.Employee.FirstName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) || x.Employee.LastName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) || x.ProjectExperiences.Any(y => y.ProjectTitle.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) || y.Description.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)) || x.Tags.Any(t => t.Title.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)))
.ToList();
```

Below is the query that is executed by EF:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C1], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id1] AS [C2], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id2] AS [C3], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id3] AS [C4], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id4] AS [C5], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id5] AS [C6], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id6] AS [C7], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id7] AS [C8], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id8] AS [C9], 
    [UnionAll1].[FirstName] AS [C10], 
    [UnionAll1].[LastName] AS [C11], 
    [UnionAll1].[EnterpriseId] AS [C12], 
    [UnionAll1].[Level] AS [C13], 
    [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [C14], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id9] AS [C15], 
    [UnionAll1].[Id10] AS [C16], 
    [UnionAll1].[Title] AS [C17], 
    [UnionAll1].[CreatedDate] AS [C18], 
    [UnionAll1].[CreatedBy] AS [C19], 
    [UnionAll1].[UpdatedDate] AS [C20], 
    [UnionAll1].[UpdatedBy] AS [C21], 
    [UnionAll1].[IsDeleted] AS [C22], 
    [UnionAll1].[TagType_Id] AS [C23], 
    [UnionAll1].[ProjectExperience_Id] AS [C24], 
    [UnionAll1].[C2] AS [C25], 
    [UnionAll1].[C3] AS [C26], 
    [UnionAll1].[C4] AS [C27], 
    [UnionAll1].[C5] AS [C28], 
    [UnionAll1].[C6] AS [C29], 
    [UnionAll1].[C7] AS [C30], 
    [UnionAll1].[C8] AS [C31], 
    [UnionAll1].[C9] AS [C32], 
    [UnionAll1].[C10] AS [C33], 
    [UnionAll1].[C11] AS [C34], 
    [UnionAll1].[C12] AS [C35], 
    [UnionAll1].[C13] AS [C36], 
    [UnionAll1].[C14] AS [C37], 
    [UnionAll1].[C15] AS [C38], 
    [UnionAll1].[C16] AS [C39], 
    [UnionAll1].[C17] AS [C40]
    FROM  (SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Join7].[FKEmployeeCvId] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], 
        [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id3], 
        [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id4], 
        [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id5], 
        [Extent7].[Id] AS [Id6], 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id7], 
        [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id8], 
        [Extent4].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent5].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Extent6].[EnterpriseId] AS [EnterpriseId], 
        [Extent7].[Level] AS [Level], 
        [Join7].[Id] AS [Id9], 
        [Join7].[Id] AS [Id10], 
        [Join7].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Join7].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
        [Join7].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Join7].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate], 
        [Join7].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], 
        [Join7].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
        [Join7].[TagType_Id] AS [TagType_Id], 
        [Join7].[ProjectExperience_Id] AS [ProjectExperience_Id], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C11], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C12], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C13], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C14], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C15], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C16], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C17]
        FROM         (SELECT [Var_41].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_41].[Employee_Id] AS [Employee_Id]
            FROM [dbo].[EmployeeCv] AS [Var_41]
            WHERE ([Var_41].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_42].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_42].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Var_42].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_42]
            WHERE ([Var_42].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent1].[Employee_Id] = [Extent2].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_43].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_43].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Var_43].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_43]
            WHERE ([Var_43].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent1].[Employee_Id] = [Extent3].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_44].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_44].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Var_44].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_44]
            WHERE ([Var_44].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent4].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent1].[Employee_Id] = [Extent4].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_45].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_45].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Var_45].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_45]
            WHERE ([Var_45].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent5] ON ([Extent5].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent1].[Employee_Id] = [Extent5].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_46].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_46].[EnterpriseId] AS [EnterpriseId], [Var_46].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_46]
            WHERE ([Var_46].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent6] ON ([Extent6].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent1].[Employee_Id] = [Extent6].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_47].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_47].[Level] AS [Level], [Var_47].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_47]
            WHERE ([Var_47].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent7] ON ([Extent7].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent1].[Employee_Id] = [Extent7].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent8].[FKEmployeeCvId] AS [FKEmployeeCvId], [Extent9].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent9].[Title] AS [Title], [Extent9].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Extent9].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Extent9].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate], [Extent9].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], [Extent9].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent9].[TagType_Id] AS [TagType_Id], [Extent9].[ProjectExperience_Id] AS [ProjectExperience_Id]
            FROM  [dbo].[EmployeeTags] AS [Extent8]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_48].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_48].[Title] AS [Title], [Var_48].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Var_48].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_48].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate], [Var_48].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], [Var_48].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Var_48].[TagType_Id] AS [TagType_Id], [Var_48].[ProjectExperience_Id] AS [ProjectExperience_Id]
                FROM [dbo].[Tag] AS [Var_48]
                WHERE ([Var_48].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent9] ON [Extent9].[Id] = [Extent8].[FKTagId] ) AS [Join7] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join7].[FKEmployeeCvId]
        WHERE (contains([Extent2].[FirstName], @p__linq__0)) OR (contains([Extent3].[LastName], @p__linq__1)) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[ProjectExperience] AS [Extent10]
            WHERE (([Extent10].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL)) AND ([Extent10].[Type] = N''Draft'') AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent10].[EmployeeCv_Id]) AND ((contains([Extent10].[ProjectTitle], @p__linq__2)) OR (contains([Extent10].[Description], @p__linq__3)))
        )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  [dbo].[EmployeeTags] AS [Extent11]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_49].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_49].[Title] AS [Title]
                FROM [dbo].[Tag] AS [Var_49]
                WHERE ([Var_49].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent12] ON [Extent12].[Id] = [Extent11].[FKTagId]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent11].[FKEmployeeCvId]) AND (contains([Extent12].[Title], @p__linq__4))
        ))
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
        2 AS [C1], 
        [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Extent14].[Id] AS [Id1], 
        [Extent15].[Id] AS [Id2], 
        [Extent16].[Id] AS [Id3], 
        [Extent17].[Id] AS [Id4], 
        [Extent18].[Id] AS [Id5], 
        [Extent19].[Id] AS [Id6], 
        [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id7], 
        [Extent13].[Id] AS [Id8], 
        [Extent16].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent17].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Extent18].[EnterpriseId] AS [EnterpriseId], 
        [Extent19].[Level] AS [Level], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C2], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C3], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C4], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C5], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6], 
        CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C7], 
        CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C8], 
        CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C9], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C10], 
        CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C11], 
        [Extent20].[Id] AS [Id9], 
        ''4X0X'' AS [C12], 
        [Extent20].[Id] AS [Id10], 
        [Extent20].[ProjectTitle] AS [ProjectTitle], 
        [Extent20].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent20].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], 
        [Extent20].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
        [Extent20].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate], 
        [Extent20].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], 
        [Extent20].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
        [Extent20].[SequenceOrder] AS [SequenceOrder], 
        [Extent20].[EmployeeCv_Id] AS [EmployeeCv_Id], 
        [Extent20].[CvProfile_Id] AS [CvProfile_Id], 
        [Extent20].[AssociatedSchedulingProject_Id] AS [AssociatedSchedulingProject_Id], 
        [Extent20].[Customer_Id] AS [Customer_Id], 
        [Extent20].[Employee_Id] AS [Employee_Id]
        FROM         (SELECT [Var_50].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_50].[Employee_Id] AS [Employee_Id]
            FROM [dbo].[EmployeeCv] AS [Var_50]
            WHERE ([Var_50].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent13]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_51].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_51].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Var_51].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_51]
            WHERE ([Var_51].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent14] ON ([Extent14].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent13].[Employee_Id] = [Extent14].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_52].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_52].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Var_52].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_52]
            WHERE ([Var_52].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent15] ON ([Extent15].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent13].[Employee_Id] = [Extent15].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_53].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_53].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], [Var_53].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_53]
            WHERE ([Var_53].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent16] ON ([Extent16].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent13].[Employee_Id] = [Extent16].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_54].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_54].[LastName] AS [LastName], [Var_54].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_54]
            WHERE ([Var_54].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent17] ON ([Extent17].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent13].[Employee_Id] = [Extent17].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_55].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_55].[EnterpriseId] AS [EnterpriseId], [Var_55].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_55]
            WHERE ([Var_55].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent18] ON ([Extent18].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent13].[Employee_Id] = [Extent18].[Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_56].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_56].[Level] AS [Level], [Var_56].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
            FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_56]
            WHERE ([Var_56].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent19] ON ([Extent19].[Discriminator] = N''Employee'') AND ([Extent13].[Employee_Id] = [Extent19].[Id])
        INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_57].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_57].[ProjectTitle] AS [ProjectTitle], [Var_57].[Description] AS [Description], [Var_57].[CreatedDate] AS [CreatedDate], [Var_57].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], [Var_57].[UpdatedDate] AS [UpdatedDate], [Var_57].[UpdatedBy] AS [UpdatedBy], [Var_57].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Var_57].[SequenceOrder] AS [SequenceOrder], [Var_57].[EmployeeCv_Id] AS [EmployeeCv_Id], [Var_57].[CvProfile_Id] AS [CvProfile_Id], [Var_57].[AssociatedSchedulingProject_Id] AS [AssociatedSchedulingProject_Id], [Var_57].[Customer_Id] AS [Customer_Id], [Var_57].[Employee_Id] AS [Employee_Id], [Var_57].[Type] AS [Type]
            FROM [dbo].[ProjectExperience] AS [Var_57]
            WHERE ([Var_57].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent20] ON ([Extent20].[Type] = N''Draft'') AND ([Extent13].[Id] = [Extent20].[EmployeeCv_Id])
        WHERE (contains([Extent14].[FirstName], @p__linq__0)) OR (contains([Extent15].[LastName], @p__linq__1)) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[ProjectExperience] AS [Extent21]
            WHERE (([Extent21].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL)) AND ([Extent21].[Type] = N''Draft'') AND ([Extent13].[Id] = [Extent21].[EmployeeCv_Id]) AND ((contains([Extent21].[ProjectTitle], @p__linq__2)) OR (contains([Extent21].[Description], @p__linq__3)))
        )) OR ( EXISTS (SELECT 
            1 AS [C1]
            FROM  [dbo].[EmployeeTags] AS [Extent22]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Var_58].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_58].[Title] AS [Title]
                FROM [dbo].[Tag] AS [Var_58]
                WHERE ([Var_58].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) ) AS [Extent23] ON [Extent23].[Id] = [Extent22].[FKTagId]
            WHERE ([Extent13].[Id] = [Extent22].[FKEmployeeCvId]) AND (contains([Extent23].[Title], @p__linq__4))
        ))) AS [UnionAll1]
    ORDER BY [UnionAll1].[Id] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id1] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id2] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id3] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id4] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id5] ASC, [UnionAll1].[Id6] ASC, [UnionAll1].[C1] ASC',N'@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted bit,@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled bit,@p__linq__0 char(4096),@p__linq__1 char(4096),@p__linq__2 char(4096),@p__linq__3 char(4096),@p__linq__4 char(4096)',@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted=0,@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled=NULL,@p__linq__0='(sitecore)',@p__linq__1='(sitecore)',
@p__linq__2='(sitecore)',
@p__linq__3='(sitecore)                                                      ',@p__linq__4='(sitecore)                                                   '
```

When I am executing this query in the SQL MS it is giving me same error. 
Even though I can successfully execute the contains query directly on the table like this:

```
select * from Employee where contains(FirstName,'"John*"')
```

This Linq works:

```
var employeeCV = _context.Employees.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)).ToList();
```

Comment: Try to create a simpler query and reproduce the problem in a less complex scenario.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have full-text indexing enabled for ALL columns that participate in Contains function - see my answer below

Comment: This one runs fine on single table but not working on the complex queries. Any ideas how to get it working on join Queries ? I have added Linq for the query I am executing above in the question.

Comment: `I have added Linq for the query I am executing above in the question` - do not see any edit.

Comment: updated now. 
Not working:

ListOfEmployees = _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee)
    .Include(x => x.Tags)
                    .Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences).Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences)
                    .Where(x => x.Employee.FirstName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) || x.Employee.LastName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)
                    || x.ProjectExperiences.Any(y => y.ProjectTitle.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) ||
                    y.Description.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)) ||
                    x.Tags.Any(t => t.Title.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword))).ToList();

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, twice `.Include(x => x.ProjectExperiences) ` ..? That's a mistake.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake. Even removing that still giving me same error.

Comment: Seems like it is mostly because of Dynamic filters, try to disable them `_context.DisableFilter("IsDeleted");`

Comment: Thanks for that. It actually fixed my problem. Thanks heaps I have spent long time of getting it working. Also if you can provide more information why dynamic filter was causing that issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to run fulltext not on from `Employees` table, but on a `Extent2`, i.e. `SELECT something FROM Employees WHERE ...` and it is not full-text indexed. You will have to rewrite your linq query or do it in T-SQL instead of linq.

> (SELECT [Var_42].[Id] AS [Id], [Var_42].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
> [Var_42].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator]
> FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Var_42]
> WHERE ([Var_42].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted) OR
> (@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled IS NOT NULL) )
> AS [Extent2]

---

I suggest that you try to rewrite your linq query like this:

```
ListOfEmployees = from cvs in _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee) 
                  where _Context.Employees.Any(
                        e=>e.FirstName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) 
                        && e.EmployeeID == cvs.EmployeeID
                  ))

 ... etc
```

This should generate a simple `EXISTS` statement which should work OK.
It is better to use query syntax, because you can name your subqueries.

The reason why EF is doing this "mess" for you is because you use [Dynamic filters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters).

> [Var_58].[IsDeleted] = @DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_IsDeleted

If you try to disable the Dynamic filters:

```
_context.DisableAllFilters();
```

it will not help you now, since it just sets the variable `@DynamicFilterParam_IsDeleted_DynamicFilterIsDisabled` in the generated query, but the query still will contain  `[Var_xx]` subqueries, because  `EntityFramework.DynamicFilters` overrides some methods of Entity Framework. See [this link](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/issues/39).

---

Why do dynamic filters cause problems?

The reason [is mentioned here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/issues/6):

> When I specify additional filters on entity queries (using linq's
> .Where() clause, for example), those additional filters cause EF to
> create sub-tables in the query.

So Dynamic filters create subqueries and there you get your exception, it is also [well described here](https://robhead89.blogspot.com/2015/11/full-text-search-in-entity-framework-6.html). There is a similar workaround recommended:

> The workaround I'm currently using (which seems to work) is to always
> force the Full Text Index predicate into a separate sub query so the
> predicate is always executed against the base table rather than an
> intermediate result set.

So you should try to convert all the conditions that are using full-text indexes to separate EXISTS statements.

Comment: I can rewrite the LINQ. But I am not too sure what I will have to change it to include the join query instead of using Include. Also T-SQL would require lot of efforts as I will have to map all the entities manually.

Comment: Extent2 is just an alias for a projection from Employee table, the examples in the link below has both projections and joins with other tables and it does not prevent the full text search https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: I understand .. But than why it is not  working in my case ?

Comment: @ArunKumar Because in EF, unless you are really good at it, you sometimes need to check the output SQL and rewrite your linq. Try to rewrite it with `_Context.Employees.Any(e=>e.FirstName.Contains ..)` instead of `x.Employee.FirstName.Contains`, that should simplify output t-sql.

Comment: @ironstone13 No relevant example found on the MSDN link you supplied.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer.

Comment: Disabling the filters _context.DisableAllFilters(); or _context.DisableFilter("IsDeleted") not working. The query generated still has dynamic filters. I am trying to rewrite the query.

Comment: Also _context.DisableFilter("IsDeleted") throws an exception saying filter name not found.

Comment: I think that you should open the issue here: https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters/issues. I suppose that suggested rewiting of the query does not work either...?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I had the same issue, tried creating a subquery by doing `_Context.Table.Where` instead of `x.Table.Where`. The generated query still queries from an `extent`. I wonder what else can be done here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to create a full-text index in your database first, if you're using MS SQL Server - see this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx if you want to do this via sql statements, otherwise see this link - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197912(v=sql.80).aspx - if you want to do this via UI

Can you please confirm that you have full-text indexing enabled for **ALL** columns that participate in Contains function

```
select * from Employee where contains((FirstName,LastName),'"John*"')
select * from Tag where contains(Title,'"John*"')
```

Comment: OP wrote: `I can successfully execute the contains query directly on the table like this` ...?

Comment: I have already created the index. That is why I am able to execute the query directly.

Comment: In SQL you give you only use FirstName column, in EF generated query you have several columns - LastName and Title - did you include them in the index as well?

Comment: All of them are added to the index. In EF it is only complaining about FirstName.

Answer (score 0):

I end up rewriting the LINQ like this to fix the problem:

```
var listOfEmployeeCV = from cvs in _context.EmployeeCvs.Include(x => x.Employee).Include(x=>x.Tags)
                                   .Include(x=>x.ProjectExperiences)
                              where _context.Employees.Any(
                                    e => e.FirstName.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)
                                    && e.Id == cvs.Employee.Id
                              ) || (_context.Tags.Any(t=>t.Title.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) && cvs.Tags.Contains(t)))
                                || (_context.ProjectExperiences.Any(pe=>(pe.ProjectTitle.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword) 
                                || pe.Description.Contains(SearchQuery.Keyword)) && 
                                cvs.ProjectExperiences.Contains(pe)))
                               select new
                               EmployeeCvDTO
                               {
                                   Employee = new EmployeeDTO
                                   {
                                       FirstName = cvs.Employee.FirstName,
                                       LastName = cvs.Employee.LastName,
                                       EnterpriseId = cvs.Employee.EnterpriseId,
                                       Level = cvs.Employee.Level
                                       //ProfileImageData = x.Employee.ProfileImageData
                                   },
                                   Tags = cvs.Tags,
                                   ProjectExperiences = cvs.ProjectExperiences,
                               };
```

Answer (score -2):

Use raw sql through Entity Framework, it works.

rtEntities rv = new rtEntities();

```
        string query = string.Format("SELECT FT_TBL.ID, FT_TBL.Description, KEY_TBL.RANK FROM tbl_user AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN  FREETEXTTABLE(tbl_user, Description, '(free text)',   5    ) AS KEY_TBL    ON FT_TBL.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]");

         var data = rv.Database.SqlQuery<userDetails>(query).ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = data;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Ignoring that using raw sql instead of linq is pretty bad practice in general. The question is 4 years old, and this answer doesn't even answer it, it's just a suggestion for an alternative solution with irrelevant code which should've been a comment.